# Reading Text file and recording values in array using function

Tags: c

this is my first question here, i am still in learning phase of C and just beginning to write something.

I am writing a program which reads data from text file (.txt) , the file only contains numbers (eg. 10763.60) one number per line. I have written couple of lines first to calculate the number of lines in the file. then i am writing code to read the content and save it into an array.
Following is the code.

```
FILE *myFile;
myFile = fopen(filename, "r");

//read file into array
float numberArray[count];
int i;

if (myFile == NULL){
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
}
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i] );
}

fclose(myFile);
```

Now i am trying to convert it into a user define function, so that i can use it at various places in my code.
for that purpose i tried following.

```
int *datavalue(int count)
{

    float *numberArray = malloc(sizeof(float)*count);

    FILE *myFile;
    char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    printf("\nEnter file name or full path: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    myFile = fopen(filename, "r");

    //read file into array

    int i;

    if (myFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i] );
        printf("\nThe value is %0.2f",numberArray[i]);
    }

    fclose(myFile);
    return numberArray;
}
```

But i am unable to accomplish the task. How can i do this?

Comment: So what is wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Are you asking how to find out how many lines are in a file, so you can calculate the size of your array?

Comment: One thing wrong is `malloc(sizeof(int)*count);` which is the wrong data type, should be `float`. This is easier to get right if you use the pointer type, such as `malloc(sizeof *numberArray * count);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minor mistakes, 
   1) as you are working on float but allocating memory for int
   2) retruning float pointer but you declared  *datavalue(int count) as returning int*

I have modified program below program works as expected, check and correct as per the below program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 80

float  *datavalue(int count) {

   float *numberArray = malloc(sizeof(float)*count);

   FILE *myFile;
   char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
   printf("\nEnter file name or full path: ");
   scanf("%s", filename);
   myFile = fopen(filename, "r");

   //read file into array

   int i;

  if (myFile == NULL) {
      printf("Error Reading File\n");
      exit (0);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
      fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i] );
      printf("The value is %0.2f\n",numberArray[i]);
 }

 fclose(myFile);
 return numberArray;
```

}

// main program looks follows

```
 int main()
 {
   int i = 0;
   float *array=NULL;

   array = datavalue(5);
   for(i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
    printf("%f\n", array[i]);
   }

   return 0;
```

}

I see below output with above program

`The value is 12.50
The value is 14.50
The value is 16.50
The value is 18.60
The value is 6.70
12.500000
14.500000
16.500000
18.600000
6.700000`

my test file contains

`12.5
14.5
16.5
18.6
6.7
8.9
12.20`

Comment: It is showing error : conflicting types for 'datavalue'

Comment: Is there any way of combining two functions.. so that only once i have to provide the file location.. i mean one function which first read the number of lines, store it in count variable and then read the file and store the value in array..

Comment: thats is easy, just move    `FILE *myFile; char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
      printf("\nEnter file name or full path: ");
      scanf("%s", filename);
      myFile = fopen(filename, "r");`   to main(), implement one more function like   `int getDatacount(File *fp) {}`  to get count  and modify  `datavalue(int count, File *fp),`  open file in main() pass  myFile pointer and count to getavalue() ,